# Excel - Conditional Formatting using time arguments

Tags: excel, date, formatting, formula, conditional-statements

Looking to change the fill of a cell based upon the amount of time between the current date (TODAY), an entered value detailing when something was done historically and a set period from that historical date of either 6months or 1year.

E.g. I have a date of 12/04/2015 entered as a value in the cell.
Todays date is 30/8/2015.
I want the system to work out if TODAY is within 6 months of the cell value and change the colour if outside this value.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place the cell cursor to the first date in your list (here A1 for example)
- Select "Manage Rules"from the "Conditional Rules" dropdown icon
- in the dialog box select "New rule", then "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- enter formula as `=A1<TODAY()-365` ... and give it a nice "past 1 year" format
- select "New rule" / "Use a formula ..." again
- enter formula as `=A1<TODAY()-182` ... and give it a nice "past half year" format
- close the dialog with [OK]
- copy A1
- Paste Special / Format to other cells
- test by temporarily changing your system date and pressing F9 to recalculate the sheet

[image]

Comment: My pleasure ... welcome to StackOverflow ... wish you a lot of fruitfull exchanges